# IntelliJ: Regular expression to join multiple lines into single CSV line?

Tags: regex, android-studio, intellij-idea

Occasionally I need to join multiple lines of data into a single line, and in this case, specifically as comma-separated values on a single line:

input: (lines pasted into some Android Studio editor tab)

```
Rush
IQ
Saga
Yes
```

desired output:

```
'Rush','IQ','Saga','Yes'
```

**Edit > Find > Replace** I got close with this regex pattern to match newline character (\n) with goal eliminate it:

```
search: ^(.*)$\n
replace: '$1',
[x] Regex
```

but produces this undesired output:

```
'Rush',IQ
'Saga',Yes
```

because after the a new line is eliminated the following line is already adjoining so it's skipped... so we get this "every other line" behavior.

Comment: Try `(.+)(\R|\z)` => `'$1',` and then post-process by repalcing `,$` with an empty string

Comment: I would use two replacements one after the other. the first one would replace `^(.+)$` by `'$1'`, and the second one would replace `\n` by `,`.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way I could think of is to replace `\n` by `','` and then manually wrap the whole line in quotes:

The result of the first replacement would be:

```
Rush','IQ','Saga','Yes
```

And then just manually add first and last quote.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**  Concatenate the lines, use

```
(.+)(?:\R|\z)
```

Replace with `'$1',`.

The `(.+)(?:\R|\z)` pattern matches any 1+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.+`) and captures this into Group 1 and `(?:\R|\z)` matches either a line break sequence (`\R`) or (`|`) the very end of the string (`\z`).

**Step 2**: Post-process by repalcing `,$` with an empty string. This pattern matches `,` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

> Occasionally I need to join multiple lines of data into a single line, and in this case, specifically as comma-separated values on a single line:

Regex may not be the best solution for this.

## CSV library

There are several [comma-separated values (CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) libraries available to make quick work of this.

The libraries will handle a particular problem you may overlook in writing your own code: Some of your lines of input having the **single-quote mark within their content**. Such cases need to be escaped. Quoting [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) section 2.7:

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:

> ```
>   "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Here is an example of using [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library.

We use lambda syntax with a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) to get an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) of the lines of text from your input.

We specify using a single-quote, as you desire, rather than default of double-quote in standard CSV.

We use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close the `CSVPrinter` object, whether our code runs successfully or throws an exception.

```
String input = "Rush\n" +
        "IQ\n" +
        "Saga\n" +
        "Yes";

Iterable < String > iterable = ( ) -> new Scanner( input ).useDelimiter( "\n" );  // Lambda syntax to get a `Iterable` of lines from a `String`. 

CSVFormat format =
        CSVFormat
                .RFC4180
                .withQuoteMode( QuoteMode.ALL )
                .withQuote( '\'' );
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try (
        CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter( stringBuilder , format ) ;
)
{
    printer.printRecord( iterable );
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String output = stringBuilder.toString();

System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run:

> output: 'Rush','IQ','Saga','Yes'

We can shorten that code.

```
try (
        CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter( new StringBuilder() , CSVFormat.RFC4180.withQuoteMode( QuoteMode.ALL ).withQuote( '\'' ) ) ;
)
{
    printer.printRecord( ( Iterable < String > ) ( ) -> new Scanner( input ).useDelimiter( "\n" ) );
    System.out.println( printer.getOut().toString() );  // Or: `return printer.getOut()` returning an `Appendable` object. 
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not that this is particularly better shortened. Personally, I would use the longer version wrapped in a method in a utility class. Like this:

```
public String enquoteLines( String input ) {
    String output = "";
    Iterable < String > iterable = ( ) -> new Scanner( input ).useDelimiter( "\n" );  // Lambda syntax to get a `Iterable` of lines from a `String`.

    CSVFormat format =
            CSVFormat
                    .RFC4180
                    .withQuoteMode( QuoteMode.ALL )
                    .withQuote( '\'' );
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (
            CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter( stringBuilder , format ) ;
    )
    {
        printer.printRecord( iterable );
        output = printer.getOut().toString();
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output;
}
```

Calling it:

```
String input = "Rush\n" +
        "IQ\n" +
        "Saga\n" +
        "Oui";

String output = this.enquoteLines( input );
```